# Show in datepicker javascript the months indicated by dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Select Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        var today = new Date();
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            autoclose:true,
            endDate: "today",
            minDate:"today",
            maxDate: "+2m"
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
            });


        $('.datepicker').keyup(function () {
            if (this.value.match(/[^0-9]/g)) {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9^-]/g, '');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to show only indicated moths in a datepicker, i mean if a dropdown outside datepicker has the options by item  by example one option is January-February-March,second option is April-May-June i want the datepicker only show these months, i want it to show by trimester selected in the dropdown menu, is this possible?

Comment: its about a datepicker using javascript

Comment: @user1538301 It's pretty obvious he's talking about the JQuery UI date picker since he has those libraries loading with his `script` elements.

Comment: @ScottMarcus There was no code originally. But you are right, it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely possible.  You may want to check the API documentation for more info, but in general JQueryUI date pickers can be restricted like:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
} );
```

You would simply want to check the `val()` of your other dropdown before displaying the date picker and restrict accordingly.

Example from https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max which also notes that you can set restriction range to specific dates like `(new Date(2009, 1 - 1, 26))` if you prefer that over calculating offsets.